# Structure of JavaScript OOP

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm absolutely new to JavaScript OOP and I would like to ask you. Could someone tell me if my code structure is fine or not? Coz I really searched information related to JavaScript structure, but couldn't find that. So I don't know how to write certain methods,objects and etc. Besides that, could someone share me some useful information about how JavaScript OOP code should look like? :/ Thanks

Here is my code:

```
function Date() {
this.validateDate = function() {
    var twoDates = {
        inputDate: new Date($('#employmentDate').val()),
        todaysDate: new Date
    }
    return inputDate.getTime() < today.getTime();
}

this.documentReady = function() {
    $( document ).ready(function() {


$('[name="Submit"]').on('click', function(e) {

    console.log('test click');


    if (!this.validateDate()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('prevented');
    }
})
})
}

this.documentChange = function() {
  $('#employmentDate').change(function() {
 console.log('Check after change');
if (!this.validateDate()) {
    console.log('Wrong date');
    alert ("Entered date is later than today's date");
    }
})
}
}
var date= new Date();
date.validateDate();
date.documentReady();
date.documentChange();
```

Comment: `how JavaScript OOP code should look like?` There is no definite answer to that. It all depends on how you would like you objects to behave.

Comment: But one thing proponents of just about all flavors of JavaScript OOP would probably agree on would be that shadowing the built-in `Date` constructor is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here you find a german example.](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

[Here you find an english example.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS)

1. Build your own constructor `function XYZ(parameters){ //define members }`
2. Add functions to your constructor `XYZ.prototype.functionName = function(){};`
3. Initialize your object with `var xyz = new XYZ(parameters);`

These are the basic steps for `Javascript OOP`, but be careful to not overwrite / shadowing `native constructors/objects` as the `Date` in your example.

There is no definition to your question, because everybody would use it in an other way. You need to find your style of coding. You have your `basics` here now. So get a look and find out by **trial and error** :-)

```js
function Person(firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
}

Person.prototype.sayHello = function() {
  console.log("Hello, I'm " + this.firstName);
};

var person1 = new Person("Alice");
var person2 = new Person("Bob");

// Aufrufen der Methode sayHello der Person.
person1.sayHello(); // logs "Hello, I'm Alice"
person2.sayHello(); // logs "Hello, I'm Bob"
```

Answer (score 1):

Some things to improve in your code:

1. Indent your code properly.
2. Don't redefine `Date`, but use a different name for your own constructor
3. Don't put DOM dependencies in your constructor (employmentDate, submit), but pass such dependencies as arguments to the constructor, or expose properties to allow the caller to set them.
4. Keep the wait for the document-ready event out of your object: just do it once in your main script.
5. When using `this` in callbacks, make sure to set the context. You can use `.bind(this)`.
6. Unless you have some constraints, define methods on the prototype instead of the individual object instance. Constraints preventing you to do this could be that you need access to private variables.

Here is how I would adapt your code:

```js
// Use a custom name, not one that is already used. 
// Pass dependencies to the object instance.
function DateVerifier(submitButton, dateElement) {
    this.$submitButton = $(submitButton);
    this.$dateElement = $(dateElement);
    
    // Assume DOM is loaded, 
    // and set the event handlers during the construction of this object
    this.$submitButton.on('click', function(e) {
        console.log('test click');
        if (!this.validateDate()) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('prevented');
        }
    }.bind(this)); // bind the callback's context to your object (for `this` to work)

    this.$dateElement.change(function() {
        console.log('Check after change');
        if (!this.validateDate()) {
            console.log('Wrong date');
            alert ("Entered date is not valid date before today's date");
        }
    }.bind(this)); // bind the callback's context to your object (for `this` to work)
}

// Methods can be set on the prototype
DateVerifier.prototype.validateDate = function() {
    // Creating an object here is overkill, just do:
    var todaysDate = new Date().getTime();
    var inputDate = Date.parse(this.$dateElement.val());
    // Also check whether the input date is a valid date
    return !isNaN(inputDate) && inputDate < todaysDate;
}

// Keep the document-ready thing out of your object. 
// You just need it once in your main script,
// which also gives you a closure at the same time:
$(function () {
    // Pass the dependecies as arguments
    var dateVerifier = new DateVerifier('[name="Submit"]', '#employmentDate');
    dateVerifier.validateDate();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    Employment date: <input id="employmentDate">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```